# Tidying NES cumulative data set in R: What is the best format to download and how to separate these variables

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, survey

I am looking at the American National Election Survey cumulative data set [found here](https://electionstudies.org/data-center/). They only have .ascii, .dta, and .sav files for download. I chose to download a .dta file. I imported it into my working directory using the downloader package, and then unzipped the file.

```
downloader::download(url = 
       "https://electionstudies.org/anes_timeseries_cdf_dta/",
                        "anes_timeseries_cdf_data.zip", mode = "wb")
unzip(zipfile = "anes_timeseries_cdf_data.zip", 
  files = c("anes_timeseries_cdf.dta", "anes_timeseries_codebook.pdf"), 
  list = FALSE, 
  unzip = getOption("unzip"))
```

Then, using the readstata13 package, I imported the .dta file into a data frame.

```
read_anes_cdf <- read.dta13("anes_timeseries_cdf.dta", 
                   convert.factors = TRUE, 
                   generate.factors = TRUE, 
                   nonint.factors = TRUE)
```

I really played around with that function until I could get it to run with minimal warnings. Now I am trying to get the data into workable shape. Selecting and renaming the variables was easy (I'll demonstrate the code with only one variable):

```
var_anes_cdf <- read_anes_cdf %>%
    select(c("VCF0104")) %>%
    rename('respond_gender' = 'VCF0104')
```

However, the data frame includes both the coded variable and the description in every observation (i.e. respond_gender has values of "1. Male", "2. Female", and "0. NA; no Pre IW"). So I tried separating out the coded variables from their descriptions with separate()

```
var_anes_cdf %>%
    separate("respond_gender", into = c("respond_gender", "descrip"), sep = ".")
```

It printed out the variables I selected in the last step, but the respond_gender and new "descrip" variable were both empty. It also returned: "Warning message:Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 59933 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...]."

I'm having a really difficult time working with this data. Is .dta the best file type for me to be working with, or should I have picked the .ascii or .sav files instead? How can I fix the problems I am having with the tidying process?

Comment: The problem is that the separator you specify with `sep` is interpreted as a regular expression. The dot is interpreted as any character in regex and thus you have to escape it first `sep = "\\."`.